# Is there have some practices to split NSArray for multithread processing?

Tags: objective-c, concurrency

I need to process 1000 objects with 4000 objects in relation, it takes me half minute for now, and i thought that maybe exists some techniques to split array of objects on multithread to process?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

If your device has more than one core for CPU, you could try something like this:

```
    NSArray *sourceArray = @[@(1), @(2), @(3)]; //// Replace this one with your own source
    NSMutableArray *targetArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSLock *aLock = [NSLock new]; //// NSMutableArray is not thread safe
    [sourceArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [aLock lock];
        [targetArray addObject:object];
        [aLock unlock];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You read about dispatch_apply? Maybe it help you... [Link at guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW2)